# Error importing jfxtra jar into scene builder 2.0

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder, jfxtras

I'm creating an app using [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org) in Scene Builder 2 but I'm unable to import the `jfxtras-all-8.0-r5.jar` file into Scene Builder. When I show the JAR Analysis report in Scene Builder I get errors similar to the one shown below for every single class. How do I fix this issue?

```
Exception for: jfxtras/internal/scene/control/skin/agenda/AgendaDayListSkin.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: jfxtras.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.AgendaDayListSkin
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jfxtras.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.AgendaDayListSkin.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
... 13 more
```

Comment: SceneBuilder 2 is kind of out of date, you should try with a more up do date version: Currently [Scene Builder 8.2](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/)

Comment: I tried with Scene Builder 8.2 but am still getting the same issue. The Custom menu that is supposed to come up after importing a jar or fxml file isn't showing up and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Add the comment to tbeernot's answer and he will get notification.

Comment: I'll take a peek. I'm still suspecting that this has to do with the changes that were made to the Skin class. But that probably won't be today; Friday or this weekend.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Please let me know if any changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the one from Gluon and the latest Java 1.8 
http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

The all-in-one jars are back in the maven repo's. (R6-SNAPSHOT for now).

Comment: I am using Java 1.8 and I tried it with Scene Builder 8.2 but am still getting the same issue. The Custom menu that is supposed to come up after importing a jar or fxml file isn't showing up and I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Importing the third release worked but the fourth and fifth releases both didn't work.

Comment: The all jars in maven central are 1kb large. They never worked.